# How to integrate using scipy with an array as part of the function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I would like to use the integral command in scipy and have a function that gets multiplied by each element in the array once.

```
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad, romberg
import scipy.special as special
from numpy import sqrt

yes = np.array([0,1])

def integrate(x,yes):
    return x+yes

result = quad(integrate,0,1,args=(yes))

print(result)
```

when I do this I get the error 
**only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**

But if I do this

```
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad, romberg
import scipy.special as special
from numpy import sqrt

yes = np.array([0])

def integrate(x,yes):
    return x+yes

result = quad(integrate,0,1,args=(yes))

print(result)
```

it gives me this **(0.5, 5.551115123125783e-15)** 
Which is exactly what I want, but I would like it for each element in the array.

Is there a way to write a for loop? 
I've also heard of **scipy.integrate.quad_vec**, but that was not working. Thank you in advance

Comment: `args` is supposed to get a tuple.  `(yes)` is not a tuple, it is just `yes`.  `args=(yes,)` is the correct way of passing variable `yes` to your function. That said, `quad` can only integrate one value; your function needs to return a scalar.

Comment: How do i get my function to return a scalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy), it's fully vectorized. Just make sure that your function `f`, if given an input `x` of a particular length/shape, returns an object of shape `range_shape + x.shape`. The result will be of shape `range_shape`.

```py
import numpy as np
from quadpy import quad


def f(x):
    return np.add.outer(np.array([0, 1]), x)


val, err = quad(f, 0, 1)
print(val)
```

```
[0.5 1.5]
```

Comment: Nice shout out for `quadpy` - thanks!